# How to access a url parameter in template using Symfony (not within the action)?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, url-parameters

Using Symfony to access url parameters in an action like this

```
$this->getRequestParameter('myUrlParameter');
```

How can I access this parameter in the root template, where I am not within the action? I tried many things already like

```
echo $context->getRequest()->getParameter('pool');
```

and

```
echo $context->getParameter('pool');
```

Which didn't work. With

```
echo sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentInternalUri();
```

I get the whole url - which is not what I want.
I feel like there must be a simple way to access this information ...

Comment: The easiest thing would probably be to simply use `$_GET`. (However, you should think about whether your template is the right place to do this in the first place. Sounds like it might rather belong into the controller.)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the request object from the template directly like this:

```
$pool = $sf_request->getParameter('pool');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it to the view via controller:

```
public function yourController(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->myUrlParameter = $this->getRequestParameter('myUrlParameter');
}
```

Trying to access it directly, you are fighting with the framework, not using it.